# uuid maybe empty string in postgres

Tags: node.js, uuid, postgresql-9.6

Here I create an empty table and a function:

```
CREATE TABLE "ebook_info_t" (
    "ebook_id" uuid NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY ("ebook_id")
);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_ebook_f(
    IN author text,
    OUT existid uuid, OUT isexist bool)
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
    rc uuid := NULL;
    bkname text :=NULL;
BEGIN
    SELECT ebook_id,title INTO rc，bkname FROM ebook_info_t WHERE author_name=author;
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'bookid=%, title=%',rc,bkname;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call this function in nodejs by pg module which version is 6.1.2.
Firstly, table `ebook_info_t` is empty. I call function `add_ebook_f` then recieve `bookid=3d6171d3-3d45-4869-8e89-b8975a31246b, title=thebookname`.
Secondly, I remove `WHERE-condition`. Then I call it again. I recieve `bookid=bac22a64-9cb2-440a-be39-b40d74c2ddfb, title=<NULL>`.
Finally, I test this function in pgAdmin4. I shows `ERROR:  bookid=<NULL>, title=<NULL>`.
If the book is not exist, I want to insert it to table. But if I call `add_ebook_f` in nodejs, I could not judge this book exist or not.
So my question is, how can I insert book info to table if it is not exist? In other words, could I know this book exist?

Comment: why not using `coalesce` for null values and `NO_DATA_FOUND` for empty table?..

Comment: I do more test shows in update. I'm not good at postgres. Do you know what happened in postgres? thx.

Comment: please, compress your question to: 1. what you have, 2. what you want, 3.how you do it, and 4. what is your question about it.

Comment: It seems a bug of pg module. I update to version 6.1.5 and it works well. thx your help!